# Calling random objectId from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

On my Parse data console in my class VoteCount, I have a vertical column of String data called objectId, and every horizontal row of data in that class has a unique objectId. As you can see here, I'm retrieving data from objectId BiEM17uUYT:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("BiEM17uUYT") {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
            let option1 = voteCount1["optionName"] as String
            let option2 = voteCount1["optionName2"] as String
            self.showOption1.text = "\(option1)"
            self.showOption2.text = "\(option2)"

        }
```

I just don't know how to call data from a random objectId. I can only call data from a specific objectId, in this case BiEM17uUYT. How do I collect all that data from a random objectId within that whole column, rather than just specifically BiEM17uUYT?  This will allow me to update my app data purely from Parse and not make me have to constantly submit entirely new updates.

Note: Like "votes", "votes2", "optionName" and "optionName2", "objectId" is another column of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** On your class, make a variable with a number in it, increment that number so it is always unique and sequential. Then call Parse to get the total number of objects and run a RAND to get a number between 0 and your Max number. Then query for object with that number in the right field.

**Longer answer:** Try something like this:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (count: Int, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    randNumber = arc4random_uniform(count)
    query2.whereKey("voteNumber", equalTo:randNumber)
    query2.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
      (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
      if error != nil {
        NSLog("%@", error)
      } else {
        let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
        let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
        let option1 = voteCount1["optionName"] as String
        let option2 = voteCount1["optionName2"] as String
        self.showOption1.text = "\(option1)"
        self.showOption2.text = "\(option2)"

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now, I'm getting an error on query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock stating that 'Int32 is not a subtype of Int'.  I tried changing count: Int to count: Int32 but that won't work either.  Any idea why that is?